# Better way to call a class method in ruby?

Tags: ruby, jruby

I need to call a class method in ruby, where I receive the method name as a string, and I already know the class.

Is there a better way than this?

```
(X.method method_name.to_sym).call

(X.method method_with_params_name.to_sym).call(param1, param2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `send` which is at least a bit cleaner and more common.

```
TheClass.send(method_name)
TheClass.send(method_name, param1, param2)
```

Comment: so I *have* to resort to send? I mean, is there any other way?

Comment: @rmk: what other way were you hoping there was?  Is there some problem with using "send"?

Comment: Hmm... I don't know, which is why I asked :)

Comment: @rmk: There are tons of ways. `send` is the simplest and most idiomatic.

Comment: @Chuck: post some other ways in an answer, I'm curious!